# hashmap is different outside of while loop

Tags: java, hash, while-loop, hashmap, alias

I'm not sure why the hashmap is printing out different things inside this while loop and outside of the while loop. I declared the map outside the while loop, so I assumed that it should be the same inside and outside. In the code, I have the same print statement inside the while loop and outside of it, but they are printing different things. The key for the map is personCounter, which increments and should be unique. Would really appreciate your help.

```
    public Map<Integer, double[]> setRating(CSVReader r, int taskNum, int taskWeightNumHeader) 
        throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    String[] line;
    int personCounter = 0;

    Map<Integer, double[]> indivTaskRating = new HashMap<Integer, double[]>();
    while ((line = r.readNext()) != null) {
                    double[] perTaskWeight = new double[5];
        personCounter++;
        int multiplier = taskNum * 5;   
        perTaskWeight[2] = Double.parseDouble(line[taskWeightNumHeader + multiplier]);
        perTaskWeight[1] = Double.parseDouble(line[taskWeightNumHeader + multiplier + 1]);
        perTaskWeight[0] = Double.parseDouble(line[taskWeightNumHeader + multiplier + 2]);
        perTaskWeight[3] = Double.parseDouble(line[taskWeightNumHeader + multiplier + 3]);
        perTaskWeight[4] = Double.parseDouble(line[taskWeightNumHeader + multiplier + 4]);
        indivTaskRating.put(personCounter, perTaskWeight);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j ++) {
            System.out.println("personID: " +1+ ", rating: " +indivTaskRating.get(1)[j]);
        }       
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j ++) {
        System.out.println("personID: " + 1+ ", rating: " +indivTaskRating.get(1)[j]);
    }
    return indivTaskRating;
}
```

Comment: Now that you have edited your question, the existing answers are invalid, which is not very helfpul. I suggest that you rollback the edit, try to debug your code and if you can't find your issue, post a new question with the new information.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same double array in ***every*** entry you place in the map. At the end it will be populated with the same values for each entry!

You need to reallocate the array on each iteration of your while loop to fix the problem.

```
while ((line = r.readNext()) != null) {
    double[] perTaskWeight = new double[5];

    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You keep reusing the same array, so you actually overwrite its content at each loop (while).

You need to create a new instance (`double[] perTaskWeight = new double[5];`) within the while loop.

Comment: I guess `override := overwrite`

Comment: So I moved the perTaskWeight to inside of while loop, the values for indivTaskRating.get(1)[j] inside the while loop changes. Does the hashmap make a copy of the array if the array goes to the garbage collection? @assylias

Comment: @cinnamontoast As long as your map holds a reference to the array, it can't be garbage collected (and no the map does not copy the content of the array, it only holds a reference to the array).

Comment: @assylias How can I fix it so that indivTaskRating stores a different array every time going through the while loop? I tried moving the new instance inside the while loop. The values still change aren't consistent.

Comment: @cinnamontoast As explained in my (and the other) answer, move the array initialisation: `double[] perTaskWeight = new double[5];` inside the while loop.

Comment: @assylias I tried moving the new instance to inside the while loop. But was getting inconsistent value for the same key, which was why I asked about garbage collection. If the new instance is inside the while loop, how is the hashmap going to refer to the old one after one iteration?

Comment: @cinnamontoast `double[] perTaskWeight = new double[5];` creates a new array of size 5 and makes `perTaskWeight` "point" to that new array. But the previous array is still in memory, and if you have stored it in your map, it is still rachable (through the map), even if you don't explicitly have a variable "pointing" to it.

Comment: @cinnamontoast I suggest you debug your code step by step to better understand what values are going into your map. If you fail to find the issue, you will need to create a simple but complete example that compiles and reproduces your issue so others can test it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28249/discussion-between-cinnamon-toast-and-assylias)

Comment: @cinnamontoast sorry but I don't have time now.